# How do you deploy phonegap app to Ipad?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

Hi I am using phonegap 3 and am having trouble getting my app to deploy to my Ipad.

The app runs fine in a simulator however when i try to deploy locally I get no device found.

I have a valid developer certificate and can run xcode projects on my Ipad fine.

```
$ phonegap run ios
[phonegap] detecting iOS SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the local environment
[phonegap] compiling iOS...
[phonegap] successfully compiled iOS app
[phonegap] trying to install app onto device
[phonegap] no device was found
[phonegap] trying to install app onto emulator
```

I have read through the docs and can't seem to find any troubleshooting information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok turns out that running locally isn't supported in the current version so I am just running the xcode project from the platforms/ios folder and deploying from there.

Comment: Is there any documentation on this? Would be good to keep track on when it becomes supported.

Comment: I don't think so, I was only able to find this out by asking in the #phonegap irc channel